# CanvasGradient type error in NPM package text-to-image

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, node-canvas

I am trying to create an image using a given text so I used npm's text-to-image package but it's giving me an error when compiling typescript. I am getting the below errors when running the typescript compilation command. It's coming from the node_modules folder

```
node_modules/text-to-image/dist/textToImage.d.ts:2:24 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'CanvasGradient'.

     bgColor?: string | CanvasGradient | CanvasPattern;
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/text-to-image/dist/textToImage.d.ts:2:41 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'CanvasPattern'.

     bgColor?: string | CanvasGradient | CanvasPattern;
                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/text-to-image/dist/textToImage.d.ts:13:17 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'CanvasTextAlign'.

     textAlign?: CanvasTextAlign;
```

I have already installed node-canvas as suggested in text-to-image docs.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the canvas either in server.js file or where you have imported the text-to-image:

`import 'canvas';`